# ActiveWorkbook is Nothing when running a VBA macro from C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, vba

I am trying to write a Winform application and dock Excel inside it as a control. Everything works until I tried to run an Excel macro (written in VBA) from my c# app. When ***this macro*** tried to access ActiveWorkBook, it is Nothing.

Funny thing is, if I comment out the "SetParent(xlHwnd, this.Handle);", the ActiveWorkBook is available. Seems like the window state of Excel application is affecting the current ActiveWorkbook.

Below is my code:

```
xlApp = newMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

xlApp.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMinimized;

xlApp.DisplayFormulaBar = false;

xlApp.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = false; 

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

xlApp.DisplayStatusBar = false;

xlApp.Interactive = true;

xlApp.Visible = true;

xlHwnd = (IntPtr)xlApp.Hwnd;

//Windows API call to change the parent of the target window.

SetParent(xlHwnd, this.Handle);

//Wire up the event to keep the window sized to match the control

SetWindowPos(xlHwnd, 0, this.DisplayRectangle.Left, this.DisplayRectangle.Top, this.DisplayRectangle.Width, this.DisplayRectangle.Height, 0X0040 | 0X4);

this.SizeChanged += newEventHandler(Panel1_Resize);

xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();            

vardbAddIn = (AddIn)xlApp.AddIns[3];            

if(dbAddIn != null)

{

   WorkbookdbWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dbAddIn.FullName);

   if(dbWorkbook != null)
   {

          dbWorkbook.Application.Run("myMacro1");

   }

}
```

Comment: Your code has no reference to `ActiveWorkBook` in it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The "ActiveWorkBook" is in the macro. So the exception actually happens when the macro get called.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN you have to use ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook in your macro because this is the one that contains the macro.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-thisworkbook-property-excel